# The number of rational roots of polynomial $ x^3 - 3x - 1$ is?

Tags: cubics

How exactly can I find no. of rational roots, not only for this but similar type of questions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the rational root theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Hint: By rational root theorem, the numerator of any rational root (in simplest form) divides the constant, and the denominator divides the coefficient of the highest power. In this case, they are $-1$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rational Root theorem issue](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625168/rational-root-theorem-issue)

Comment: @mlc , It isn't a duplicate of this question, since she was not knowing what rational root theorem is, how can she had a issue with that?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare: point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove that this equation has no rational roots by contradiction.

Suppose $x=  \dfrac pq$ (Rational) is a root of this equation , where $\gcd (p,q) =1$

Now put the value of $x$ in the equation :

$$ \Big (\frac{p}{q} \Big )^3  - 3 \Big (\frac{p}{q} \Big ) -1=0 \implies p^3-3pq^2-q^3=0$$

Now take a look at the following cases :

**Case 1 :** If $p$ is even $\implies$ $q$ is also even. Not possible , since $\gcd (p,q) =1$

**Case 2 :** If $p$ is odd, and $q$ is also odd , This expression can never be zero.
 (odd $-$ odd $-$ odd $\neq 0$)

**Case 3 :** If $p$ is odd, and $q$ is even, again, this expression can never be zero. 
(odd $-$ even $-$ even $\neq 0$)

Our assumption was wrong.

**Therefore, this equation has no rational root.**

Comment: Thanks I get it now, btw can you help me by telling how exactly I can write mathematical equations here?

Comment: @ItiShree Put a dollar sign in beginning and one in the end to write in $LaTeX$ (i.e. coding language for writing math ) . You can click 'edit' on your question (or my answer) to see that how coding is done.For further help : See this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for helping. It's much easier now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem which states that all and only rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients are to be searched among the ones of the form $\frac ab$ where $a\in\Bbb Z$ divides the known term and $b\in\Bbb Z$ (obviously $b\neq0$) divides the coefficient of the highest power.

So in your case all and only rational roots could be $\pm1$, but plugging them into your polynomial, you'll easily see that none of them is a root.